# How to prove $f:\mathbb R→[0,1]$ with $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$ and $f(x)=x$ for $x\in[0,1]$, $f(x)=1$ for $x\geq 1$ is not an open mapping?

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1]$ be defined as$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0; & x \le 0\\
x; & x \in [0,1]\\
1; & x \ge 1
\end{cases}
$$
Why it is not an open mapping?

Answer (score 3):

Because $U=(-\infty, 0)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open, but $f(U)=\{0\}\subseteq [0,1]$ is not open.

Comment: oh I am so stupid. quite simple

Comment: thank you very much for answering this

Comment: @ShenChong You are welcome